# Как в Midnight Commander удалять с возможностью востановления?

Tags: linux, mc

Можно ли в Midnight Commander настроить удаление в корзину?

Comment: Нет это другой вопрос. Там про команду `rm` здесь про Midnight Commander.

Comment: Я не знаю что там вызывается, но вряд ли консольная программа. В любом случае `alias rm=trash` не помог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MC использует функцию [unlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) для удаления файлов.

Для виртуальной ФС используется ссылка `path_element->class->unlink`. Для локальной файловой системы [метод определен вот тут: src/vfs/local/local.c#L200](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/src/vfs/local/local.c#L200).

```
...
return unlink (path_element->path);
...
```

Хороший ответ есть в [wiki Archlinux.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Midnight_Commander_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B6.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B7.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.8B)

Используется [libtrash](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~marriaga/software/libtrash/) для перехвата системных вызовов удаления файлов и папок. Вместо этого файлы перемещаются в определенную папку.

Использование:

```
alias mc='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtrash.so.3.3 mc'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. F9
2. Настройки
3. Конфигурация...
4. Прочие настройки
5. Галочка "Безопасное удаление"

Comment: Не сработает. Если включить "безопасное удаление", то просто в диалоге удаления фокус будет на кнопке "Нет".

Comment: Ну, если действительно нужна корзина, то надо пользоваться командой *trash*, тогда удаление будет в корзину. Но как на это настроить клавишу F8 я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Нет такого "из коробки" в MC. Функционал "корзины", как таковой, зависит от используемого дистрибутива и окружения. Как вариант, можно прикрутить к системе libtrash. Ну или патчить mc для замены удаления на перемещение во временный каталог.

Comment: Не видел реализации корзины в дистрибутивах и окружениях, не совместимой с freedesktop

Comment: хотя libtrash может такой и есть..)